# handling null value returned with JSON

Tags: json, ruby, linux

I'm running ruby 1.9. And I have this code which is extracting value of `Status` and `State` from these two `/usr/sbin/storcli /c0/bbu show j` & `/usr/sbin/storcli /c0/cv show j` commands.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'json'

output_bbu = %x{/usr/sbin/storcli /c0/bbu show j}
output_cv = %x{/usr/sbin/storcli /c0/cv show j}

begin
        j = JSON.parse(output_bbu)
        k = JSON.parse(output_cv)
        result = j["Controllers"][0]["Command Status"]["Status"]

        ### I'm not sure how to get the value of "State" and store it in "status" variable.

        status = k["Controllers"][0]["Response Data"]["Cachevault_Info"][0]["State"]
        status = j["Controllers"][0]["Response Data"]["BBU_Info"][0]["State"]

        ###
rescue Exception => e
        puts "CRITICAL: error reading BBU status: #{e}"
        exit 2
end

if result != 'Success'
        puts "CRITICAL: command not successful, result: #{result}"
        exit 2
end
```

**Problem** :

One of the two commands `storcli /c0/cv show j` or `storcli /c0/bbu show j` is returning null value in "status" variable and script fails with error

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Either `storcli /c0/cv show j` could return nil value of "State" or `storcli /c0/bbu show j` could return nil. So what I would like to do is store the value of "State" in variable "status".

Sample output of command,

```
$ storcli /c0/cv show j

{
"Controllers":[
{
        "Command Status" : {
                "Controller" : 0,
                "Status" : "Success",
                "Description" : "None"
        },
        "Response Data" : {
                "Cachevault_Info" : [
                        {
                                "Model" : "CVPM02",
                                "State" : "Optimal",
                                "Temp" : "35C",
                                "Mode" : "-",
                                "MfgDate" : "2013/09/17"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
]
}
```

See, here it returned value of "State" as "Optimal", So I would like to store the value of it in variable "status."

Sample output of nil,

```
$ storcli /c0/bbu show j

{
"Controllers":[
{
        "Command Status" : {
                "Controller" : 0,
                "Status" : "Failure",
                "Description" : "None",
                "Detailed Status" : [
                        {
                                "Ctrl" : 0,
                                "Status" : "Failed",
                                "Property" : "-",
                                "ErrMsg" : "use /cx/cv",
                                "ErrCd" : 1001
                        }
                ]
        }
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't getting a "Response Data" from the one command you can use the following

```
status = k["Controllers"][0]
           .fetch(["Response Data"], {})
           .fetch(["Cachevault_Info"], {})
           .fetch([0], {})["Status"]
status ||= j["Controllers"][0]["Response Data"]["BBU_Info"][0]["State"]
```

With the `||=`, if the results from `status = k` are `nil` it will set `status = j`

Comment: I have concern with only `State` value irrespective of command. Not "Status" from "Detailed Status".

Comment: if there is no "State" from bbu, then use `storcli /c0/cv show j` command and store the value in "status"

Comment: thanks for your update, but I'm still getting `CRITICAL: error reading BBU status: undefined method []' for nil:NilClass`